# APEX 3.2: The Same unique ID on two different pages

Tags: oracle-apex

I have two separate pages:

- Page A: Main page where user submits an issue
- Page B: Attachments page

Page A will have a unique ID assigned when the page is submitted.  I would like to have a button on Page A that allows a user to add attachments to the issue.  When a user clicks on that button the attachments page (Page B) will open in a separate window and they can add attachments to the issue. When they click the 'Complete' button on Page B, the attachments are added to a different table but have the corresponding unique ID from Page A.

How do I carry over the unique ID from Page A to Page B and add that ID to one or multiple attachments for a singe issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save the unique ID into a page item when the user clicks your new button on Page A, you can reference that value on Page B.